# VBA to Add Multiple Content Controls to a Single Table Cell in Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I need to add multiple content controls and additional text into a single table cell in word using VBA. Here is an example of what I need:

<CC1>Moby Dick</CC1> has been read by <CC2>2</CC2> people who have given it an average score of <CC3>3</CC3> out of 5

I know I can add a single content controls with the following syntax:

```
With rng.ContentControls.Add(wdContentControlRichText)
 .title = "Book Name"
 .Tag = "title"
End With
```

If my range is set to the cell, how would I make the following pseudo code work:

```
Set rng = objDoc.Tables(1).Cell(2, 1).Range

With rng.ContentControls.Add(wdContentControlRichText)
 .title = "Book Name"
 .Tag = "title"
End With

" has been read by "

With rng.ContentControls.Add(wdContentControlRichText)
 .title = "People Count"
 .Tag = "count"
End With

" people who have given it an average score of "

With rng.ContentControls.Add(wdContentControlRichText)
 .title = "Score"
 .Tag = "score"
End With

" out of 5"
```

Here is some actual code. It is putting the third insertafter and content control between the Second insertafter and the second content control

```
With rng.ContentControls.Add(wdContentControlRichText)
    .title = "Asset ID"
    .Tag = "asset_id"
End With
rng.InsertAfter " | Rev. "
rng.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
rng.Move wdCharacter, -1
With rng.ContentControls.Add(wdContentControlRichText)
    .title = "Revison Number"
    .Tag = "revision_num"
End With
rng.InsertAfter " | Effective Date: "
rng.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
rng.Move wdCharacter, -1
With rng.ContentControls.Add(wdContentControlRichText)
    .title = "Effective Date"
    .Tag = "effective_date"
End With
```

[image]

Comment: You just need to move the range before each insertion. E.g. see [`Collapse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.range.collapse), [`Move`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.range.move), [`InsertAfter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.range.insertafter)

Comment: @TimothyRylatt I've tried following what your links indicate but this is not making sense. If the range starts as a cell, It's not letting me insert a new content control after the first one is created. and the first text is inserted after. It inserts the second content control in the next cell and not in the first cell after the text.

Comment: That’s because the range includes the end of cell marker. Collapse the range to the end and use `Range.Move wdCharacter, -1` to exclude it.

Comment: @TimothyRylatt Thanks, but it is still not working. I've update my question above with what is happening. I've tried moving things around, but it doesn't change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
   Set rng = objDoc.Tables(1).Cell(2, 1).Range
   rng.Collapse wdCollapseStart
   With rng.ContentControls.Add(wdContentControlRichText)
      .Title = "Effective Date"
      .Tag = "effective_date"
      .SetPlaceholderText Text:="Effective date"
   End With
   rng.Text = " | Effective Date: "
   rng.Collapse wdCollapseStart
   With rng.ContentControls.Add(wdContentControlRichText)
      .Title = "Revison Number"
      .Tag = "revision_num"
      .SetPlaceholderText Text:="Rev Num"
   End With
   rng.Text = " | Rev. "
   rng.Collapse wdCollapseStart
   With rng.ContentControls.Add(wdContentControlRichText)
      .Title = "Asset ID"
      .Tag = "asset_id"
      .SetPlaceholderText Text:="Asset ID"
   End With
```

Comment: Interesting. Building it in reverse works. Thank you for the assist.